# How to get code coverage in SonarQube for MAVEN multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have configured SonarQube scanner for maven multi-module project and its working fine and i'm getting the data about bugs, code-smells, Vulnerabilities and Duplicated Blocks etc.

**This is my sonar-projects.properties file**

```
sonar.projectKey=MyProject
sonar.projectName=My-Project
sonar.login=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.binaries=/home/build_dir/My-Project

sonar.modules=module1,module2

module1.sonar.sources=myModule1,test
module2.sonar.sources=mybModule2,test
```

Here I'm getting the results/data for Lines of Code, Bugs, Vulnerabilities, Code Smells, Duplications for both modules but i don't know why my "Coverage" column is showing 0.0%.

Can any one help me on this

**FYI:** I have integrated the `maven-clover-plugin` to get the code coverage report but i don't have idea how can i integrate these reports with Sonar

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You have a Maven project, so you should use [SonarQube Scanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven). At the beginning remove `sonar-projects.properties` file, and next execute the scanner:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.clover.reportPath=target/clover-report.xml
```

It is the only SonarQube Clover plugin I found:[sfeir-open-source/sonar-clover](https://github.com/sfeir-open-source/sonar-clover). You have to install it on the server. Unfortunately, it is very old, so I'm not sure if it possible to feed SonarQube with Clover reports.

Comment: Thanks agabrys, but here I have multiple clover.xml files(for each module) can you please suggest me how can I use sonar scanner for each and how it will reflect in sonar porta.

Comment: Did you try it? The path to XML report is relative. If you have `target/clover-report.xml` file in every module, then it should work.

Comment: While running command getting error: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project MyProject: Error when executing blame for file CODE_PATH/SomeLibrary.java: svn: E170001: Authentication required for '<https://my.svn.net:443> Authorization Realm' -> [Help 1]` , Don't know why it is asking for SVN authentication

Comment: Don't mix Clover reports and JaCoCo.

Comment: Julien you are right, I was tired and wrote a wrong answer.